# 'int' object is not callable only appears randomly

Tags: python, runtime-error

Sometimes this code works just fine and runs through, but other times it throws the int object not callable error. I am not real sure as to why it is doing so.

```
for ship in ships:
    vert_or_horz = randint(0,100) % 2
    for size in range(ship.size):
        if size == 0:
            ship.location.append((random_row(board),random_col(board)))
        else:
            # This is the horizontal placing
            if vert_or_horz != 0 and ship.size > 1:
                ship.location.append((ship.location[0][0], \
                                      ship.location[0][1] + size))
                while(ship.location[size][1] > len(board[0])) or \
                     (ship.location[size][1] < 0):
                    if ship.location[size][1] > len(board[0]):

                        ship.location[size][1]((ship.location[0][0], \
                                              ship.location[0][1] - size))
                    if ship.location[size][1] < 0:
                        ship.location[size][1]((ship.location[0][0], \
                                            ship.location[0][1] + size))

            # This is the vertical placing
            if vert_or_horz == 0 and ship.size > 1:
                ship.location.append((ship.location[0][0] + size, \
                                      ship.location[0][1]))
                while(ship.location[size][1] > len(board[0])) or \
                     (ship.location[size][1] < 0):
                    if ship.location[size][1] > len(board[0]):
                        ship.location[size][1] \
                            ((ship.location[0][0] - size, \
                              ship.location[0][1]))
                    if ship.location[size][1] < 0:
                        ship.location[size][1] \
                            ((ship.location[0][0] + size, \
                              ship.location[0][1]))
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 217, in <module>
  File "python", line 124, in create_med_game
    ship.location[size][1]((ship.location[0][0], \
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: Can you post the traceback for the error?  Also, something must be changing for that error to appear sometimes and not others.

Comment: Given that you are using `random` to make decisions in your code, that the error appears randomly is not surprising. Please include the *full traceback* of the error in your question. Without that this question can't be answered easily as you are asking us to manually comb your code for the possible error cause.

Comment: My first suspicion is that it has something to do with lines like this: `ship.location[size][1]((ship.location[0][0], ship.location[0][1] + size))`.  If `ship.location[size][1]` is an int, it would result in an error like that.

Comment: I have not used stack overflow a lot so it would be nice if you weren't so quick to down vote questions and put them on hold before getting any responses from me, thanks.

Comment: Your traceback is missing the source code lines; this can happen when you run this code directly in Idle. What is line 124 in your code? What is line 217?

Comment: Sorry I am still learning exactly how to post everything and make it look the way it should. I noticed for the second half (the vertical placing) that i was targeting and replacing the horizontal part when i should have been replacing the vertical part. That may be part of the issue

Comment: @BrodieMather: it isn't. What is the code supposed to do?

Comment: `(ship.location[0][0],  ship.location[0][1] - size)` is a `tuple`. It seem you have to assign it to `ship.location[size]`. Try this `ship.location[size] = (ship.location[0][0],  ship.location[0][1] - size)`

Comment: I changed that and some other things to make it work better but now I have an infinite loop. I am trying to determine why.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call (use the `..(...)` syntax) on an integer here:

```
ship.location[size][1]((ship.location[0][0], \
                        ship.location[0][1] - size))
```

`ship.location[size][1]` is an integer, and you are trying to call it by passing in the tuple `(ship.location[0][0], ship.location[0][1] - size)` as the arguments.

Your code makes this mistake in more than one place; other examples include

```
ship.location[size][1]((ship.location[0][0], \
                    ship.location[0][1] + size))
```

and

```
ship.location[size][1] \
    ((ship.location[0][0] - size, \
      ship.location[0][1]))
```

and

```
ship.location[size][1] \
    ((ship.location[0][0] + size, \
      ship.location[0][1]))
```

The backslash there still joins the physical line into a logical line, so the `(...)` calls still apply to the integers.

It is not clear to me what you wanted to do with that expression, however, so I can't offer any remedy here.

Comment: Ok I will explain the logic. It is basically a battleship game. I am trying to place the ships on a 10 X 10 grid randomly. This code is to handle the need of placing all parts of one ship horizontally or vertically. My logic in the particular lines in question is to overwrite any coordinate that was placed outside the borders of the board with a different successive coordinate. Hope that helps

Comment: @BrodieMather: so you want to use the lower or the higher of the two values? Then use assignment and call `min()` or `max()`.

Comment: If it goes above the max of the board then i need to stop placing coordinates that are on the right side of the starting point and start placing them on the left of the ship. Does that make sense?

Comment: @BrodieMather: sure, but I don't know what is in your variables. I don't know how you organised this. All I can tell you at this point is why you get your error.

Comment: Ok i adjusted my code, so that the vertical placing code properly evaluates and targets the coordinates. It resolved the error and worked twice but not it keeps going into an infinite loop....

Answer (score 0):

In any spot where the code looks like this:

```
ship.location[size][1]((ship.location[0][0], \
              ship.location[0][1] - size))
```

The simple solution was that I needed to assign it to the location:

```
ship.location[size] = ((ship.location[0][0],ship.location[0][1] - size))
```