# int object is not callable, with random liblary, python

Tags: python, random, integer

I was coding 0 - player game with random library, the error often accrues after thousands of iterations for no apparent reason, I am using only `random.randint` so there is no need for
rounding, I have seen similar question like this but with no answer because user didn't send enough error traceback, here is link:

['int' object is not callable only appears randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38079862/int-object-is-not-callable-only-appears-randomly)

my code looks like that:

```
inventory = 0
sprint = 0
dirt = 0
stone = 0
wood = 0
plank = 0
stick = 0
craftingTable = 0
woodPick = 0
stonePick = 0

def randomMove():
    global inventory
    global sprint
    if inventory == 0:
        if sprint == 0:
            randomed = random.randint(0, 10)
            listOfActions = [rightH, rightC, leftH, leftC, W, A, S, D, angleRandomize, openInventory, startSprint]
            listOfActions[randomed]()
        else:
            randomed = random.randint(0, 10)
            listOfActions = [rightH, rightC, leftH, leftC, W, A, S, D, angleRandomize, openInventory, stopSprint]
            listOfActions[randomed]()
    else:
        randomed = random.randint(0, 1)
        listOfActions = [closeInventory, craft]
        listOfActions[randomed]()

def rightH():
    global dirt, stone, wood, woodPick
    rand = random.randint(0, 1)
    if rand == 0:
        rand = random.randint(0, 99)
        if rand < 74:
            if woodPick == 0:
                print("Broke stone, not dropped")
            else:
                print("Broke stone")
                stone += 1
        if 74 < rand < 99:
            print("Broke dirt")
            dirt += 1
        if 98 < rand:
            print("Broke wood")
            wood += 1
    else:
        print("Holding Right Click")

def rightC():
    print("Clicking Right Click")

def leftH():
    print("Holding Left Click")

def leftC():
    print("Clicking Left Click")

def W():
    print("Going forward")

def A():
    print("Going left")

def S():
    print("Going backwards")

def D():
    print("Going right")

def angleRandomize():
    x = random.randint(-180, 180)
    y = random.randint(-90, 90)
    print("Randomized angle, looking " + str(x) + " " + str(y))

def openInventory():
    global inventory, sprint
    print("Opening inventory")
    inventory = 1
    sprint = 0

def closeInventory():
    global inventory
    print("Closing inventory")
    inventory = 0

def startSprint():
    global sprint
    print("Sprinting")
    sprint = 1

def stopSprint():
    global sprint
    print("Stopping Sprint")
    sprint = 0

def craftPlanks():
    global plank, wood
    plank += 4
    wood -= 1

def craftSticks():
    global stick, plank
    stick += 4
    plank -= 2

def craftCraftingTable():
    global craftingTable, plank
    craftingTable += 1
    plank -= 4

def craftWoodPick():
    global woodPick, plank, stick
    woodPick += 1
    plank -= 3
    stick -= 2

def craftStonePick():
    global stonePick, stick, stone
    stonePick += 1
    stone -= 3
    stick -= 2

def craft():
    options = []
    if wood >= 1:
        options.append(craftPlanks)
    if plank >= 2:
        options.append(craftSticks)
    if plank >= 4:
        options.append(craftingTable)
    if plank >= 3 and stick >= 2 and craftingTable >= 1:
        options.append(craftWoodPick)
    if stone >= 3 and stick >= 2 and craftingTable >= 1:
        options.append(craftStonePick)
    if len(options) == 0:
        print("Can't craft")
    else:
        randomCraft = random.randint(0, len(options) - 1)
        options[randomCraft]()

for i in range(100000):
    inventoryStored = [dirt, stone, wood, plank, stick, craftingTable]
    print("Inventory: " + str(inventoryStored))
    randomMove()
    if craftingTable == 1:
        break
```

and error traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/***/PycharmProjects/randomMinecraftAgent/RandomAgnetWithSimulatedMinecraft.py", line 147, in <module>
    randomMove()
  File "C:/Users/***/PycharmProjects/randomMinecraftAgent/RandomAgnetWithSimulatedMinecraft.py", line 29, in randomMove
    listOfActions[randomed]()
  File "C:/Users/***/PycharmProjects/randomMinecraftAgent/RandomAgnetWithSimulatedMinecraft.py", line 141, in craft
    options[randomCraft]()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

this "simulation" is working for thousands of iterations and then it just breaks, how to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

You append the option `craftingTable` which is defined as an integer. Instead you want to append the `craftCraftingTable`.

Comment: I am so stupid lol, thanks so much